# How do I get the ABOUT ME heading to appear above the picture and intro

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Right now, the heading  appears on the left of the picture. I tried decreasing the width & height of the picture. The headings look fine on the rest of the page, just doesn't sit right with this section.

```
<section id="about">
      <div id="pic">
        <h1 class="headings">ABOUT ME</h1>
        <img src="images/planner.jpg" alt="">
        <div id="intro">
          <h2>Michelle Lyn</h2>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi id, vel nihil aperiam exercitationem cum accusamus assumenda doloribus perferendis, eligendi dolorem iure! Nemo culpa, provident quis aliquam impedit sed maiores eaque! Sapiente officiis sit repudiandae sed! Quo voluptates quas animi! </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>


/* About Section */
#about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#pic {
    display: flex;

}

#pic img {
    width: 575px;
    height: 400px;
}

#intro {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;   
}

#intro h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the heading on the left, because it is inside the `#pic` which has `display: flex` and so it renders everything inside in a single row.

I can recommend 2 options how to change that.

1)Remove the `.headings` from the `#pic`. So your html looks like:

```
<section id="about">
  <h1 class="headings">ABOUT ME</h1>
  <div id="pic">
    <img src="images/planner.jpg" alt="">
    <div id="intro">
```

2)Add `flex-wrap` to your `#pic` without modifying html. The changes in the CSS:

```
#pic {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.headings {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
```

```css
#about {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

#pic {
    display: flex;

}

#pic img {
    width: 575px;
    height: 400px;
}

#intro {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: justify;
    padding: 10px;   
}

#intro h2 {
    font-size: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section id="about">
      <h1 class="headings">ABOUT ME</h1>
      <div id="pic">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/200/200" alt="">
        <div id="intro">
          <h2>Michelle Lyn</h2>
          <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Excepturi id, vel nihil aperiam exercitationem cum accusamus assumenda doloribus perferendis, eligendi dolorem iure! Nemo culpa, provident quis aliquam impedit sed maiores eaque! Sapiente officiis sit repudiandae sed! Quo voluptates quas animi! </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```